# How To Set TimeZone in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, timezone, uidatepicker

I am creating an Application where the app sends a email to a selected email when he/she chooses a time they want (for eg: an Appointment) and clicks a button. The Email Works but The Time They Choose gets Converted To GMT + 0 instead of my local time. I tried searching this up but no luck so far. 
I am trying to configure the timezone on an UIDatePicker and is there any option or code that can solve this?

I want to set the timezone to GMT + 3 or I want the application to detect  the timezone automatically.

```
@IBAction func SendButton(_ sender: Any) {
        showMailComposer()

           showMailComposer()

        print(ServiceA)
    }

    func showMailComposer() {

        guard MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() else {
            //Show alert informing the user
            return
        }

        let composer = MFMailComposeViewController()
        composer.mailComposeDelegate = self
        composer.setToRecipients(["mohid.sheraz@outlook.com"])
        composer.setSubject("Booking")
        composer.setMessageBody("Name: \(nameField.text!) \n\nPhone: \(emailField.text!) \n\nDate/Time: \(datePicker.date)", isHTML: false)

        present(composer, animated: true)
    }

    func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {

           if let _ = error {
               //Show error alert
               controller.dismiss(animated: true)
               return
           }

           switch result {
           case .cancelled:
               print("Cancelled")
           case .failed:
               print("Failed to send")
           case .saved:
               print("Saved")
           case .sent:
               print("Email Sent")
           @unknown default:
               break
           }

           controller.dismiss(animated: true)
       }
```

Comment: You should [edit] your question to include all relevant code in the form of a [mcve] to make it on-topic.

Comment: Like How? sorry i am new.

Comment: Just check out the linked help site. For editing your question, you just need to click on the link in my comment :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use a Swift DateFormatter to make the date more human readable and adjust for timezone differences.

```
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .long
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = .none

    // Then select your timezone.
    // Either by abbreviation or defaulting to the system timezone.
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "EST")
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current

    let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
```

Good luck!